# How do I specify the Royal Observatory at Greenwich as a PyEphem observer?

Tags: astronomy, pyephem

The [PyEphem package](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/index.html) provides the ability generate an [Observer](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#observers) instance by providing the name of a city to the `ephem.city()` utility function, but seems to lack a way of specifying the [Royal Observatory at Greenwich](http://www.rmg.co.uk/visit/get-here) as a city.

Is there a name recognized by PyEphem that corresponds to the Royal Observatory at Greenwich? Is there a list somewhere of the cities that PyEphem recognizes?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct — the Royal Greenwich Observatory is not a city and not available through the `city()` function. Instead, you will have to create its location manually:

```
gw = ephem.Observer()
gw.lat = '51:28:36.7'
```

(Note that you do *not* have to set the `lon` of the `Observer` because observers start out with zero as their latitude and longitude if you are not more specific.)

Comment: Is there a list of available cities somewhere?